# Quit LightDM & launch a new x-session with an alternative xorg.conf

Tags: bash, xorg, multiple-monitors, 15.10, lightdm

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 with the following configuration:
LightDM, XFCE, set to one screen across two physical monitors running from two outputs on a single NVIDIA card.

This is my normal environment where I can drag windows/apps/etc between the monitors, play Steam games (most let me choose which monitor to play on) and do general office stuff like have email on one screen and a word processor doc on the other

I also have X-Plane flight simulator, where the ideal way to run across two screens is to have two instances of X-Plane running with each one accessing its own physical monitor.

For X-Plane, I like to open a new terminal with CTRL-ALT-F1 and then run the following. This runs X-Plane with no desktop environment:

xplane.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service lightdm stop

xinit /home/ashley/Launch_Scripts/XP64.sh

echo  "Restart desktop ? (y/n)"
read response
if [ "$reponse" = "y" ]
then
sudo service lightdm start
fi
# end of script
```

And XP64.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank
/home/ashley/X-Plane\ 10/X-Plane-x86_64 > /dev/null 2>&1
#
# Replace the above with these for two instances
#DISPLAY=":0.0" /home/ashley/X-Plane\ 10/X-Plane-x86_64 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
#DISPLAY=":0.1" /home/ashley/X-Plane-Slave/X-Plane-x86_64 > /dev/null 2>&1

#endofscript
```

The piping to /dev/null is recommended by the X-Plane users who came up with the script as the flight sim itself is very chatty.

All works well, X-Plane runs as the desktop does (1x screen across 2x monitors) and looks brilliant. However its a little unrealistic - the centre of the two screens is centred on the view from the L or R sitting position in the aircraft and not as you would see when flying for real.

Hence the recommendation that two individual screens should have two individual instances of X-Plane, one for the student pilot or first officer and another where (usually) the instructor pilot or captain would sit.

I've created another **xorg.conf** this time with two individual screens, and confirmed this works by putting in place of my usual xorg.conf - two completely separate screens, I can move the cursor between them but can't drag a window.

What I can't figure out is, in the X-Plane bash scripts above, if & how I could call upon a separate xorg.conf when launching via xinit.

I've tried:

```
xinit /home/ashley/Launch_Scripts/XP64.sh -config /path/to/modified.xorg.conf
```

But it just ignores me - wherever I put the modified xorg.conf, whatever permissions I give it.

My first question is am I going about this the right way?

Ultimately I want to be able to run two instances of X-Plane, each on one an individual screen/monitor, but also revert to my single screen (across two monitors) for my normal day-to-day stuff.

My second question is, if so, what I am doing wrong? (I think its loading the default xorg.conf from /etc/X11/ whatever I specify in the script)

Should I post my xorg.conf files here too?

I'm not closed to the idea of creating another session (i.e.: like choosing from XFCE or Unity from the login screen) with its own settings if that would be easier to manage.

Comment: Have you read `man xinit`? If not, that's your first mistake.

Comment: @waltinator    The man page did me some pointers but I missed the division between client options & server options. I'll post an answer as it might help others trying to do similar.

Answer (score 0):

Error was in syntax:

```
xinit /home/ashley/Launch_Scripts/XP64.sh -config /path/to/modified.xorg.conf
```

Should be:

```
xinit /home/ashley/Launch_Scripts/XP64.sh -- -config modified.xorg.conf
```

Both *xorg.conf* and *modified.xorg.conf* are located in */etc/X11/*